# How can i get picture by having the URL?

Tags: c#, silverlight, facebook

I need to find the way to show image on my application form by having only the URL of the image.

How can i do it ?

The application is silverlight application and the URL can be an image from facebook

Comment: i dont know how to do it .. get the image by having the URL .. i did not try anything

Comment: Use a web browser? This question doesn't make any sense. There is nowhere *near* enough information to actually answer it.

Comment: Is this a web application or a windows form ?

Comment: the URL can be picture from facebook for example

Comment: Show where? Show how? What GUI framework? What version of framework? What's the context? Do you need to cache it? Have you tried simply googling, considering this is a very basic kind of question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For WinForm you could use `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` class. Have a look at this [link](http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com/2010/03/download-image-given-url-in-c-using.html).

For silverlight you could do

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://test.com/abc.jpg"); //just a dummy uri  
YourImage.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is a Windows Forms application:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
using(Stream stream = wc.OpenRead(imageUri))
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without better information about your program, then this you can have a look at the WebClient class. It has methods to download files:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx